# Need to produce "real" double quotes in LaTeX and XY-pic in Emacs

Tags: emacs, xy-pic

I am using Emacs as a text editor on Xubuntu. I am using the XY-pic package to make some commutative diagrams, and I need the following command (which is inside figure, center, and xy begin tags):

```
(0,0)*+{\mathbb{S}^3\cup\mathbb{S}^3\cup\mathbb{S}^3\cup\mathbb{S}^3}="4S3";(0,-20)*+{\mathbb{S}^3}="S31";
```

The meaning is not really important if you don't know XY-Pic, but see those double quotes, ie "4S3"? Those are important! All of the following break during compile (I get runaway argument errors):

```
`4S3' ``4S3'' ''4S3'' ``4S3``
```

The problem is that on Emacs, I can't seem to make those "close double quotes". I type various things but always end up with single backwards or forwards quotes.

My current solution is to write the double quotes in a different editor (I can't quite remember what I originally used, possibly gedit) and copy the required quotes over to Emacs. Then they show up correctly! There has to be a better way; does anyone know of one?

Comment: It may depend on the settings of Emacs; in order to get the straight double quote I hit the `"` key twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `c-q "` (`c-q` quotes the next character, so emacs doesn't interpret it, `"` is an active character in emacs LaTeX mode that inserts correct opening/closing quotes).

Also, as per egreg's comment, your emacs may be set so that hitting the " twice will produce the correct quotes.